# What pins on the PS2 AV out port are the audio pins?

Tags: audio, sony-playstation

I'm trying to get some LEDs to be synced with sound. I'm trying to find the pins for the left and right audio on a fat PS2 motherboard. All I can seem to find is a pin with a solid 10v and 2 pins that seem to be synced with the brightness of the TV. All the others aren't reading any voltage.

Comment: Can you confirm that audio is actually being output through this connector? The reason I ask is that I found on my PS3 I needed to change a setting for that to happen.

Comment: @Wilson I'm not sure of the specific details, but I do recall that AV is output through the HDMI cable or the origins AV port, but not both at the same time.  When I finally got an HDTV, I had to change the output settings on the PS3.  Is that what you are referring to?

Comment: The ps3 has multi out so you can use both outputs. Its how I use my surround sound.

Answer (score 7):

I found two neat pictures that show the pin order on the AV out port and the AV cable.

[image: PS2 AV Cable]

[image: PS1 AV Out]

From the left in the bottom picture, pin 2 is the right audio channel and pin 4 is the left channel.

[Source](http://www.gamesx.com/avpinouts/psxav.htm)

Comment: Do you think the pins line up on the motherboard like that?

Comment: Ayy, thay do. Unfortunately they don't push out enough voltage to do what I want. Thanks for the help JAL.

Comment: @Justin If you need more power, pin 10 is a 5 volt line.

Comment: But wouldn't that corrupt the audio?

Comment: @Justin Hmm, not sure.  Either way, probably not a good idea to touch that in hindsight.

Comment: Lol, its fine. Im just going to do solid blue around the vets.

Comment: @Justin good luck!